# Is an encrypted hard drive immune from malware if it is not mounted when using a LiveCD?

Tags: malware, disk-encryption

As a follow-up to [the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53190672#53190672) in `The DMZ`, is an encrypted drive (full disk encrypted e.g. LUKS, BitLocker) protected against malware if it is not mounted when using a LiveCD?

The use case is that no other devices are available and there is a need to inspect potentially malicious files.

The assumptions are;

- The malware is not designed to wipe drives and for malware to wipe a drive it must be executed on the host that has a decrypted volume/partition.
- When a drive is fully encrypted, there are no unencrypted blocks that the malware can write to without mounting the drive.
- Malware can only affect an encrypted drive if it is mounted decrypted.
- If malware is executed, when running a LiveCD, it is limited to memory and cannot affect firmware or BIOS.
- Methods such as `dd` are not considered to be part of the threat model.

Note: The use of drive is synonymous with disk for the avoidance of doubt.

Answer (score 4):

It's protected in the sense that malware cannot be installed on the unmounted encrypted drive. However it's still possible for the encrypted drive to be damaged or destroyed if the drive can be written. A simple **dd** to the raw unmounted drive can destroy it.

```
 ----  Edit  ----
```

If the encrypted drive is a bootable drive, then there is an unencrypted boot partition that could in theory be modified in an "Evil Maid" equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I elaborated the question that commands such as `dd` are not part of the threat model as this resembles `wiperware`

Comment: @Ryan: it is still possible that the malware does not wipe the device but instead encrypts the (already encrypted device) with a key only known to the attacker. While the attacker has no access to the unencrypted data themselves they can still demand a ransom to allow the user access to the drive again. This would not be wiperware but ransomware.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Can the disk be encrypted by the attacker if it is not mounted? Is the ransomware attack OS dependent? For example, if the device is booted via a Linux LiveCD, what is the likelihood of a ransomware attack?

Comment: Anything you can do, so can the attacker. I'm not sure why you are ruling out dd. However since you are running a live CD nothing presently installed on the system you're inspecting should be *running* unless you deliberately run something outside of the Live CD, you should be pretty safe in general terms.

Comment: @Ben - The reason I ruled out `dd` is because the data on the disk while sensitive isn't critical for an availability perspective i.e. if data is lost as a result of a disk being wiped, it can be restored from backup.

Comment: @Ryan: The attacker can read and write disks and partitions on it no matter if they are mounted or not. These are just treated as some kind of special file.  Mounting is only needed to let the OS interpret the data of this special "file" as a file system in order to let the OS access the files on it. But this is not actually needed for encrypting the disk as the disk itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Gotcha. If the data is considered to be sensitive but not critical from an availability perspective, would it be fair to state that the risk of a disruptive attack against an encrypted drive such as a wipe or encryption is low or a non-issue? The primary objective is to protect the underlying encrypted files from being compromised or exfiltrated.

Comment: @Ryan: yes, the attacker can only access the encrypted data assuming the encryption is strong enough.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Do you mean that an attacker cannot access the encrypted data if there is sufficient entropy?

Comment: @Ryan: The attacker can access the encrypted data but cannot decrypt these if encryption is strong. Sufficient entropy is not the same as strong encryption - a strong password does not help much when using a dumb encryption algorithm.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - That make sense. I imagine the risk of a weak algorithms with solutions such as Veracrypt are non-existent. Is forward secrecy an issue with to consider?

Comment: @Ryan: *"Is forward secrecy an issue with to consider?"* - I don't think that this makes any sense in the context of disk encryption since there is no key exchange involved here. But you might check at [crypto.se] to get better experts about this topic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I would have thought it would be a possible consideration from the perspective that similar to a private key, an encryption key would be open to a similar attack.